# Having Trouble with Simple Java Game

Tags: java

I am writing a program for a class in which a player and computer are playing a game. The game consists of picking 1, 2, 3, or 4 matchsticks. The player to pick the last stick out of 21 loses. The game is rigged so that the computer always wins.

Anyway, my problem lies within the logic of ending the game. Here is my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String player;
    int matchstick;
    int total = 0;

    System.out.println("Rules of the game: \nThe player and computer take turns picking 1, 2, 3 , or 4 matchsticks."
                        + " \nThe player to pick the last stick out of 21 loses.");
    System.out.print("\nHello player. Please enter your name: ");
    player = keyboard.next();

     while (total < 21) {

        System.out.print("\nHow many matchsticks do you pick, " + player + "? ");
        matchstick = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (matchstick > 4) {
            System.out.print("You have exceeded the limit of 4 matchsticks. Please try again. \n\nHow many matchsticks do you pick? ");
            matchstick = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        total += matchstick;

        System.out.println(player + " has picked " + matchstick + " matchstick(s) and brings the total to " + total + " matchsticks.");

        if (total == 21) {
            System.out.println("You picked the last matchstick... YOU LOSE!!!");
        }

        System.out.println("\nNow it's the computer's turn.");

        if (matchstick == 1) {
            total += 4;
            System.out.println("The computer chooses 4 matchsticks, bringing the total to " + total + " matchsticks.");
        }
        if (matchstick == 2) {
            total += 3;
            System.out.println("The computer chooses 3 matchsticks, bringing the total to " + total + " matchsticks.");
        }
        if (matchstick == 3) {
            total += 2;
            System.out.println("The computer chooses 2 matchsticks, bringing the total to " + total + " matchsticks.");
        }
        if (matchstick == 4) {
            total += 1;
            System.out.println("The computer chooses 1 matchstick, bringing the total to " + total + " matchsticks.");
        }

    }

}
```

}

When the condition of the while loop (total < 21) is false, how do I go about skipping the lines after System.out.println("You picked the last matchstick... YOU LOSE!!!");? Is there a way to break mid loop after the condition has been met? Or is my logic completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `return` from method `main`

```
  ...
if (total == 21) {
     System.out.println("You picked the last matchstick... YOU LOSE!!!");
     return;
}
  ...
```

Comment: Dammit!!! I knew it was something simple. I'm still a newb at this and was overthinking the problem. Thanks!

Comment: If this is the correct answer you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic completely wrong.bcz already your giving the computer chooses
values according to player values.game start by player each time.so every time player choose a value then computer.each time total=5.

```
ex: player play 4 times + computer play 4 times : total =20
```

then player should have to play.So player will fail each times.

**When the condition of the while loop (total < 21) is false**? try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String player;
        int matchstick;
        int total = 0;

        System.out.println("Rules of the game: \nThe player and computer take turns picking 1, 2, 3 , or 4 matchsticks."
                + " \nThe player to pick the last stick out of 21 loses.");
        System.out.print("\nHello player. Please enter your name: ");
        player = keyboard.next();

        while (total < 21) {

            System.out.print("\nHow many matchsticks do you pick, " + player + "? ");
            matchstick = keyboard.nextInt();

            while (matchstick > 4) {
                System.out.print("You have exceeded the limit of 4 matchsticks. Please try again. \n\nHow many matchsticks do you pick? ");
                matchstick = keyboard.nextInt();
            }

            total += matchstick;

            System.out.println(player + " has picked " + matchstick + " matchstick(s) and brings the total to " + total + " matchsticks.");

            if (total >= 21) {
                System.out.println("You picked the last matchstick... YOU LOSE!!!");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("\nNow it's the computer's turn.");

                if (matchstick == 1) {
                    total += 4;
                    System.out.println("The computer chooses 4 matchsticks, bringing the total to " + total + " matchsticks.");
                }
                if (matchstick == 2) {
                    total += 3;
                    System.out.println("The computer chooses 3 matchsticks, bringing the total to " + total + " matchsticks.");
                }
                if (matchstick == 3) {
                    total += 2;
                    System.out.println("The computer chooses 2 matchsticks, bringing the total to " + total + " matchsticks.");
                }
                if (matchstick == 4) {
                    total += 1;
                    System.out.println("The computer chooses 1 matchstick, bringing the total to " + total + " matchsticks.");
                 }
             }   
         }
    }
```

**but computer always win**